# Is there anywhere to view iOS source code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, frameworks, documentation

So the [iOS docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITabBarController) just describe the functionality of all the provided frameworks, but is there anywhere I can actually view the CODE to see how this functionality is achieved?

It ships as a binary so all that is imported legibly are the headers.  I'm just sick of reading tutorials about "use this to do that" and "look at this functionality" without any real substance behind them that I can look at

Comment: No, Apple does not provides the source code for iOS.

Comment: Is there a reason they don't?

Comment: I'm sure they have plenty of reasons. A better question is why do you think you need it? In over 5 years of iOS development I've never needed the source code to iOS to make an app.

Comment: I can certainly make do without it, however being able to see the lines of where objects belong and their capabilities and how they fit together from the people that designed them instead of plugging them in here and there with no real assurance they are in the right place doing the right thing would provide me with guidance in how to implement desired functionality, ya know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

The whole point of having specific public API is to *hide* the details of how the underlying frameworks/OS do whatever it is they do. This serves at least a couple practical purposes:

First, it protects any of Apple's trade secrets that the code might contain.

Second, it prevents 3rd party programmers from programming against a specific implementation of an API rather than the API's public contract. For example, let's pretend there is a class in UIKit called UIWidget. The public API for UIWidget says you can give it a number (an NSUInteger, let's say) and it will display a color based on that number. The public API makes no promise about what color it will pick- only that it will always be the same color for a given number. However, you have UIWidget's source code and can see that it always picks green for an even number, and red for an odd number. You then implement your whole app based on the assumption that UIWidget will always give you green for an even number, even though the public API never promises that. Then Apple releases iOS 12 with an updated UIWidget. The public API still says it will give you a specific color for a specific number, but for whatever reason Apple decided to change the implementation such that even numbers display a blue color instead. Your app is now broken because you made assumptions that were not based on the public API contract.

So while it could be educational to see the iOS source code, there are very good reasons that it is not public. There is a ton of iOS app source code out there that should illustrate whatever it is you want to do.